# can I insert multiple rows into a new table where those rows do not exist from a query using eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query

```
   $query = Modelname::selectRaw('table_name')
        ->join('table_nameTwo', 'table_name.userTwo_id', '=', 'table_nameTwo.user_id')
       ->where('table_name.user_id', '=', 8)
        ->select('table_name.user_id', 'table_name.userTwo_id', 'table_nameTwo.product')
        ->get();
```

table_name

```
id|user_id|userTwo_id
1 |8      |7
2 |2      |6
3 |8      |6
4 |8      |9
5 |8      |2
```

table_nameTwo

```
id|user_id|product
1 |2      |book
2 |2      |mouse
3 |7      |computer
4 |7      |shoes
```

The query above produces the following array from the two tables above:

```
[{"user_id":8,"userTwo_id":2,"product":"book"},{"user_id":8,"userTwo_id":2,"product":"mouse"},{"user_id":8,"userTwo_id":7,"product":"computer"},{"user_id":8,"userTwo_id":7,"product":"shoes"}]
```

table_nameThree

```
   id|user_id|userTwo_id|product
   1 |8      |7         |shoes
   2 |8      |2         |mouse
```

How do I insert the array of results ($query) into table_nameThree without duplicate rows using eloquent? (Laravel 4.2)